# SimpleMapScope not found in spring 3.0.5 jar

Tags: spring, grails

I am using Spring framework v 3.0.5.RELEASE in my grails 1.3.7 app. I found [online](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/spring/spring-3.0.5/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/SimpleMapScope.java.html) the source code for a class from the `org.springframework.beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar` named `org.springframework.beans.factory.config.SimpleMapScope` but it was not found in my jar file. Any ideas as to what's going on? I could, of course, just copy the source from that page, but I suspect I am missing something here.

Thanks,

Gene

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SimpleMapScope` is a class from Spring's `src/test` tree, i.e. it's only used internally by Spring's own unit and integration tests.  It's not part of the production JARs, and shouldn't be used by application code.

Comment: What's wrong with this class that makes it unsuitable for application code?

Comment: @Gene: I don't know, possibly nothing. But if it's in the test source tree, then the authors consider it unsuitable.

Comment: Upon further review, it's unsuitable because it doesn't clean up correctly. Thanks for your help.